# Python sendgrid send mail giving error when to_email has special characters like (

Tags: python, twilio, sendgrid

I am following the code given in sendgrid python pypi website

```
import requests
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import From, Mail, To

import config


def send_mail(
    template_id: str,
    subject: str,
    from_name: str,
    to_email: str,
) -> requests.Response:
    message = Mail(
        from_email=From(config.TEAM_EMAIL, from_name), to_emails=To(to_email)
    )
    message.template_id = template_id
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(config.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
    response = sg.send(message)
    print_sendgrid_response(response)
    return response
```

If we take any dispostable mail with special_characters like "("

I am getting error like this

```
sendgrid\base_interface.py", line 60, in send
    message = message.get()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sendgrid\helpers\mail\mail.py", line 969, in get
    'personalizations': [p.get() for p in self.personalizations or []],
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sendgrid\helpers\mail\mail.py", line 969, in <listcomp>
    'personalizations': [p.get() for p in self.personalizations or []],
                         ^^^^^^^
sendgrid\helpers\mail\personalization.py", line 250, in get
    value = getattr(self, key)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sendgrid\helpers\mail\personalization.py", line 55, in tos
    return self._get_unique_recipients(self._tos)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sendgrid\helpers\mail\personalization.py", line 39, in _get_unique_recipients
    recipient_email = recipient['email'].lower() if isinstance(recipient, dict) else recipient.email.lower()
                      ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'email'
```

This used to work in the past but it is not working right. is this the case for other people also?

Answer (score 0):

Special characters are allowed in the local part of an email address, so you could try splitting the address and then adding quotes to the everything after the @ before you send it over to SendGrid.

```py
def send_mail(
    template_id: str,
    subject: str,
    from_name: str,
    to_email: str,
) -> requests.Response:
    # Split the email address and add quotes around the local part
    local_part, domain = to_email.split('@')
    to_email = f'"{local_part}"@{domain}'
    

    message = Mail(
        from_email=From(config.TEAM_EMAIL, from_name), to_emails=To(to_email)
    )
    message.template_id = template_id
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(config.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
    response = sg.send(message)
    print_sendgrid_response(response)
    
    return response
```