Sendgrid Error: An error occurred: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "501", with message "501 Recipient syntax error"
i recently changed the validation for email addresses in my API, to accept special chars such as ñ and accent marks. I never had any problems sending emails through my API and I still don't have any problems sending them for recipients without special chars. but for the ones that do have special chars such as the ones previously mentioned, i get this error:
An error occurred: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "501", with message "501 Recipient syntax error".
I'm assuming this comes from SendGrid which is the SMTP i'm using
how could I fix this?
I'm currently using symfony 5. this is the method i use to create and send my emails:
    public function sendMail(): void
    {
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from(new Address($this->from_email, $this->from_name))
            ->to($this->to_email)
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->html($this->html);

        if (!empty($this->cc_email)) $email->cc($this->cc_email);
        if (!empty($this->bcc_email)) $email->bcc($this->bcc_email);
        if (!empty($this->file_path)) $email->attachPart(new DataPart(fopen($this->file_path, 'r'), $this->file_name));

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }

tried to send an email after changing the validation for the recipient to accept special chars. got the error:
An error occurred: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "501", with message "501 Recipient syntax error".

It seems like there's a problem with the syntax of $this->to_email. What is its value?

Or maybe cc_email or bcc_email

this->to_email would be óñsadsda@gmail.com
cc_email would be empty and bcc_email as well.
but this works perfectly for emails without special chars

So it seems that they don't understand special characters in addresses. You should contact Twilio SendGrid tech support to find out how you're supposed to handle that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76418096/1427878 suggests that wrapping the local part of the email address in double quotes might help, so perhaps try that. (The answer there appears to have the phrasing the wrong way around - everything before the @, not after.)
